# N-MOSFET and high frequencies

Tags: mosfet, frequency, high-frequency

[image]

I am using this Mosfet (http://www.vishay.com/docs/91017/91017.pdf) as a switch.
Vd is a sinusoid, amplitude = 2V
Vgs is either 0V or 5V.

In low frequencies (less than 1 MHz), everything is fine:
-if Vgs is 0V, Vs is 0V
-if Vgs is 5V, Vd is a sinusoid.

However, when I use frequencies upper than 3 MHz, Vd=Vs, whatever Vgs is (0V or 5V). I suppose that the MOSFET cannot support every frequency, but I do not see in the documentation such a limit. Is it implicit?
Thank you for your time!

Comment: posting with a circuit diagram will help.

Comment: Have a look at delay and rise/fall times

Comment: Your schematic is wrong and it won't work. Correct the schematic. Also indicate Vd in the schematic. Make sure all component values are shown.

Comment: I'd say that your schematic is even extremely wrong, If you would remove S1, R2 and Q2 the basic function would be the same. Since Q2 can be removed, no current can flow so R1 and the source are also superfluous. The most pressing error is that gate and source of the FET are shorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a MOSFET gate is a capacitor.  the data sheet will list the capacitance.  the circuit you use to drive the gate will need sufficient current drive capability to charge such a capacitor within a time smallish compared to the period of your driving signal.

another way to think of this is a low pass filter comprised of the output impedance of your gate drive circuit and the gate capacitance of the MOSFET.  this will be what limits your gate switching frequency.